# Ajax html editor an issue with VS 2013

Tags: html, visual-studio-2013, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Ajax html editor issue with VS 2013 and calendar extender is coming from Ajax but getting an issue with the Ajax html editor not showing even design mode.

Ajax html editor showing in the design mode message like:

```
HtmlEditorExtender - Unnamed1
```

Below are my web config details:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
    <add tagPrefix="cc1" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />

  </controls>
</pages>
```

Below is my Content Place Holder page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender TargetControlID="txt_largedesc" runat="server" />
```

Below is my Master Page Script Manager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />

        </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Calender Extender is coming from an Ajax tool kit, but getting issues with Ajax html editor.

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what you see in design mode?

Comment: I used this example also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/828152/Adding-AJAX-HTMLEditorExtender-control-to-a-webfor

Comment: There seem to be a bug in HtmlEditorExtender, but I can not reproduce it for now. Could you please post an [issue here](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues) with the sample project to speed up resolving of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove scriptmanager in master and add it to content page
2. install AjaxControlToolkit.HtmlEditor.Sanitizer, use Html Editor together with Html Sanitizer
3. code snippets

   ```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditor" runat="server" Width="300" Height="200" />
    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEditor"></ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>

    <asp:Button Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="Submit" />

    <br />

    <asp:Label ID="lblContents" runat="server" />
   ```

Code behind

```
 protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   lblContents.Text = txtEditor.Text;
 }
```

reference: ASP.Net AJAX Control Toolkit HtmlEditorExtender Example
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-HtmlEditorExtender-Example.aspx